# SO_KEEPALIVE does not get any response from Peer

Tags: sockets, tcp, keep-alive, tunneling

I have a situation where a SO_KEEPALIVE on my TCP socket gets no response from the peer device. I have opened the TCP socket for TCP/IP tunneling between my networked device and a Win7 Laptop. i have programmed the socket with options TCPTV_KEEP_IDLE and TCPTV_KEEPINTVL to 10 sec in order to shorten the connection timeout.

While I see the KEEPALIVE probes going out, I don't see any response from the laptop. What could be the reason?

Any assistance is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This can mean that the connectivity to the peer has been lost. Ethernet cable pull out on the peer end or intermediate router ? Capture tcpdump on the peer(laptop) and see if you are indeed receiving the keep alive probes. In all likelihood, you may not see that.

Comment: The Peer in my case in a Win7 Laptop. It's on the Win7 laptop that I saw the probes coming in (on Wireshark). Strangely, the Win7 laptop doesn't respond to it. Any possible reasons?

Comment: Can you show the Wireshark dump on the laptop?

Comment: [IMG]http://i62.tinypic.com/281x3cy.png[/IMG]

Comment: Can you see it? I don't know if I added it correctly.

192.168.1.102 is the IP of my networked device and 192.168.1.100 is the IP of the Win7 Laptop.
And thank you for your interest in helping me out.